# Can I change size of an other box with a button in it without using JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a box (Card1) with a button in it (Button is in Card1) (see the code example) and change the size of the Card 2 and card 1 (make card 2 bigger and card 1 smaller).

But the trick is that I can’t use JavaScript. First of all, is it possible or not? And if it is, how?

```css
#card1{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
#card2{
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 10%;
}
#button{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="card1">
  I am card 1
  <div id="button">
    Click me and make card 2 bigger and card 1 smaller
  </div>
</div>

<div id="card2">
  I am card2
<div>
```

Comment: No it is not because of that i just wanna know if it is possible without js i know it is possible with but is it possible without js

Comment: No this is not possible with your current HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by creating hidden checkbox, then when it's checked select any needed element *that follows it* (do not make it in inner DOM or after elements, as CSS can only select "future" nodes going from root)

Here I use checkbox state `:checked` and select all following elements with `~`

```css
#card1{
  width:50%;
  background-color:red;
  transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
}
#card2{
  width:50%;
  margin-top:1%;
  background-color:green;
  height:10%;
  transition: width 300ms ease-in-out;
}
#button{
  background-color:yellow;
}

#hidden-checkbox:checked ~ #card1 {
  width: 25%;
}

#hidden-checkbox:checked ~ #card2 {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="hidden-checkbox"/>

<div id="card1">
  I am card 1
  <label for="hidden-checkbox" id="button">
    Click me and make card 2 bigger and card 1 smaller
  </label>
</div>

<div id="card2">
  I am card2
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for thanks man :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Input type checkbox and inside the label, you can use card1 div, and using CSS checked selector (:checked) you can check the box and set the new width of the div2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).